# video flicker vlc but not totem

Tags: video, vlc, flicker

My problem started after I updated from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
I used to view videos on vlc and had no problems with videos flickering.
Things i've tried:
reinstalling vlc
changing video output
switching accelerated video output(overlay)
switching drop late frames, skip frames, quiet synchro, overlay video output
antiflickering video filter.

Totem however, plays all videos flawlessly.

Comment: I really don't mean to sound flippant, but could you just use Totem to play your video files (the "use what works" strategy)?

Comment: totem doesn't have all the functions vlc has. I am using totem now. I was just wondering if somebody knew a fix for this problem

Comment: No we can't use totem, as it it a sily player, with VLC i did not have any issues playing video on any monitor, but totem video is able to play video (on secondary monitor) in 1fps sometimes, also when the menus fades, the video stops completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was caused by deinterlace settings. I am now using yadif deinterlacing mode.